# Entity Framework (CF) - Update Disconnected entity with Complex Type

Tags: entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

i am trying to update an entity (just one column of many) while disconnected that has a complex type associated with it and with the following code, EF keeps screaming at me the Name property of the complex type cannot be null. is the following code not the correct way to do this?

```
var entity = new Customer { Id = 5 };
entity.IsDeleted = true;
dbContext.Customers.Attach(entity);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

I've also tried not initialized the complex type in the constructor but had a similar error.

Thanks!